# Deleting a node from XML using Freemarker template

Tags: freemarker

How do I use a Freemarker template to delete a node from an XML?

Input:

```
<ns:Response>
  <ns:MessageBody>
    <Header title="This title node needs to be removed."/>
    <ns:Items>
      <ns:Item>
        <ns:ItemId>1</ns:ItemId>
      </Item>
    </ns:Items>
  </ns:MessageBody>
</ns:Response>
```

Output:

```
<ns:Response>
  <ns:MessageBody>
    <ns:Items>
      <ns:Item>
        <ns:ItemId>1</ns:ItemId>
      </Item>
    </ns:Items>
  </ns:MessageBody>
</ns:Response>
```

Comment: Are you sure that freemarker is the right tool for that? :)

Comment: I have been using XSLT for it, and was wondering if Freemarker would have something built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FreeMarker's XML support is rather for the case when you have some XML in you template context (and maybe non-XML too) and you want to extract some information from that and show it in a generated HTML report or whatever you do. For transforming XML to a similar XML, well... it's maybe not a good fit. Anyway, assuming `doc` is the W3C DOM `Document`:

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={'D': 'foo'}>

<#visit doc />

<#macro @text>${.node?xml}</#macro>

<#macro @element>
  <#if .node?node_name != 'Header'>
    ${.node.@@start_tag}<#recurse>${.node.@@end_tag}<#t>
  </#if>
</#macro>
```